# How to git cherry-pick a commit with binary files

Tags: git, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick

I am trying to cherry-pick a commit from a different branch that is mostly binary files.  It seems it is mostly successful, except for one file where I get the message:

```
warning: Cannot merge binary files: XXXX.so (HEAD vs. d8ef550... Add support for 32-bit apk)
error: could not apply d8ef550... Add support for 32-bit apk
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
```

I can do a 'git add' on that file, but the results are not what I was expecting.  I expected it to be a modification, but it turned out to remove that file in question.  The commit I am trying to cherry pick modifies some binary files as well as deletes a few.

So, the question is...what is the best way to cherry-pick a commit w binary files ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do this with `git cherry-pick --strategy=recursive -X theirs {Imported_Commit}`

(You may need to abort the current cherry-pick first; `git cherry-pick --abort`)

Comment: Nice.  That worked.  I just had to explicitly do a 'git rm <filename>' and then I was right where it needed to be.  Thanks.